# Discarding a Javascript file and using another one in an HTML template page in Django 2.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I have an X.html web page which extends base.html.
X.html is a django 2.2 template and extends base.html as below :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% trans "x-box" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
```

In the base.html page I have the below jQuery included:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This jQuery is included in X.html also.
I want to discard the above jQuery for x.html and add the below jQuery in x.html :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Because the slim version causes problem for x.html. But I cannot delete slim version from base.html as it is extended by several other pages.

Comment: *I have a x.html web page which extends base.html.*  <-- Really? And how are you doing that?

Comment: HTML does not have "extending", so are you using a templating solution? If so: look up how to define blocks and override those in extending files.

Comment: I edited question and added information about django framework. This is a django 2.2 template html file. So we can extend html file from other html files.